# Centralized Logging architecture in AWS with X-Ray

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-xray

I am new in AWS and need a Centralized Logging architecture with X-Ray.
For this issue, I checked the AWS reference implementation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/centralized-logging/architecture.html which shows an interesting architecture.

My question is, how and where I should use X-Ray in such an architecture?
My goal is to have a centralized account, which will be aware, about the underlying services, especially from other accounts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS X-Ray is a distributed tracing service and not a logging service. Hence it doesn't fit into the above architecture. But if you still want to use X-Ray and have traces sent to a single common account, there's a way to do so using X-Ray daemon. If you are managing the X-Ray Daemon on your own, you can provide an IAM role of your central account which the daemon would use to send all the traces to.
Docs for daemon configuration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-configuration.html

Please keep in mind that services like API Gateway and Lambda have a self-managed daemon and currently only send traces to their own account.